# Solve set of linear equations subject to sign of results

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a set of linear equations, of the form $Ax=b$. However, the value of $b$ depends on the sign of the solution of $x$, such that $b_i = c_i + d_i$ if $x_i > 0$, and $b_i = c_i - d_i$ if $x_i < 0$.

Naturally, I could solve this by trying each combination of positiveness of $x$, but that would require solving $2^N$ sets of linear equations, which becomes unfeasible quite quickly.

Is this solvable analytically?

Comment: Can't you do this by expressing the equations in matrix form? You can write $b_i=c_i-d_i$ as $B=C-D$ where all of them are matrices and repeat same for the positive $x_i$?

Comment: @Korra: I'm not sure what you mean. I can't just define $\vec{b^+} = \vec{c} + \vec{d}$ and $\vec{b^-} = \vec{c} - \vec{d}$ because there's also vectors of $\vec{b}$ possible where $b_1 = c_1 + d_1$  but $b_2 = c_2 - d_2$. So if I want to write all possible $\vec{b}$s in an array $B$, then $B$ would have $2^N$ columns, and then I don't know how the problem "solve $Ax=B$" makes sense.

Comment: I meant that you solve the system of equations by writing it in matrix form. Then you will have two matrix equations: one for $x_i>0$ and other for $x_i<0$.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the system as $$Ax = c + Ed$$ where $E$ is a diagonal matrix whose diagonal elements are $e_i = \pm 1$.

This solves to $x = A^{-1}c + A^{-1}Ed$. You can solve this while leaving the $e_i$ as unknowns. Then you have the $x_i$ expressed as linear combinations of the $e_i$, and can quickly run through the various combinations to see which ones have $\operatorname{sign}(x_i) = e_i$ for all $i$.